# I am trying to upload a file to OneDrive through a python script but getting Invalid Hostname for this tenancy. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

The upload url is

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}/drives/Documents/items/root:/{file_name}:/content"
```

The error is:

```
{'error': {'code': 'invalidRequest', 'message': 'Invalid hostname for this tenancy', 'innerError': {'date': 'XXXX', 'request-id': 'XXXX', 'client-request-id': 'XXXX'}}}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.